# Root certificate key usage (non-self-signed end entity)

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

This discussion does *not* include self-signed end entity certificates for hosts like web servers and mail servers.

OpenSSL's default configuration for a CA certificate has the following `keyUsage`:

- cRLSign
- keyCertSign

The [Federal Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) X.509 Certificate and CRL Extensions Profile](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/pki-twg/y2002/papers/twg-02-10.pdf) has the following `keyUsage`:

- cRLSign
- keyCertSign

Microsoft uses the following for its root certificates (from [How to make a stand-alone certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888180)):

- Certificate Signing
- Off-line CRL Signing
- CRL Signing

[RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) defines CA or CRL issuer certificate key usage bits, and states the following *MAY* be present for a CA root using RSA:

- digitalSignature
- nonRepudiation
- keyEncipherment
- dataEncipherment
- keyCertSign
- cRLSign

For a DSA key under [RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), the following *MAY* be set:

- digitalSignature
- nonRepudiation
- keyCertSign
- cRLSign

And ECDSA keys under [RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), the following *MAY* be set:

- digitalSignature
- nonRepudiation
- keyAgreement
- keyCertSign
- cRLSign.

And then [RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) goes on to say with respect to ECDSA:

> if the keyUsage extension asserts keyAgreement then it MAY assert
>   either encipherOnly and decipherOnly

Why is the IETF so fast-and-loose with key usage?

Why is keyEncipherment and dataEncipherment allowed for an RSA root certificate?

Why is a key agreement usage allowed on an ECDSA certificate?

Is the IETF usage a case where the standard was crafted to fit the existing practices?

Comment: Peter Gutmann's "Godzilla Crypto Tutorial" and related pdf's are just full of X.509 examples like this, even profiles that directly contradict each other.

Comment: I'd like to give you +10 for mentioning Guttman's stuff. His Engineering Security book is kind of comical at times when he starts discussing CA and PKI failures.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`Key Usage`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) extension, when present, contains the exhaustive list of usage types that are allowed with the public key. When a system processes a certificate, it does so for a given purpose, and thus must verify that the `Key Usage` extension, if present, allows that usage. Specifically, when a system analyses a CA certificate and wants to use its public key in order to verify the signature over another certificate (that the CA purportedly issued), then this is a "certificate sign" usage; so if the CA certificate contains a `Key Usage` extension, then the system will require that the extension contains the `keyCertSign` flag.

Nothing prevents a `Key Usage` extension from containing *other* flags as well ! The verification is positive-only: systems check whether the flag they want is indeed there; they never check that a flag they don't want is absent.

Since a CA is supposed to issue certificate and CRL, it should have, on a general basis, the `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign` flags. These two flags are *sufficient*. If the CA does not intend to sign its own CRL, then it may omit the `cRLSign` flag; however, a CA without the `keyCertSign` flag makes little sense. One may want to include other flags if the CA key is meant to do other things as well (although this is not recommended: a general rule is that a cryptographic key should be used for one thing only). One may imagine, for instance, doing some *key escrowing* by encrypting the private key of issued certificates with the CA's public key, so that the CA may recover the private key under certain conditions (this is not a bad idea when the user's key is meant for data encryption).

Therefore, nothing prevents the `Key Usage` extension from containing other flags. Alternatively, the `Key Usage` extension may be missing altogether; this is equivalent to "all usages allowed".

---

Microsoft's "Off-line CRL signing" is just another name for "CRL signing". Indeed, the page you link to says this:

> To apply this key usage if a CA certificate is requested, type the following at a command prompt, and then press ENTER:
>
> **echo 03 02 01 06>File_Name.txt**

We here recognize the ASN.1/DER encoding of a `BIT STRING` of length 7 bits, with bits 5 and 6 set, and bits 0 to 4 cleared; this is the encoding of a `Key Usage` extension with flags `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign`. Though they use their own terminology, Microsoft actually conforms to the standard for that point (they did not invent a new, non-standard key usage flag for "offline CRL signing").

---

All of the above is the normal interpretation of *certificates*. It so happens that, as far as standards are concerned, "root CA certificates" *do not exist*. A "root" is called a *trust anchor* and consists in, mostly, a name (DN) and a public key. It is *Traditional* to encode trust anchor as "certificates", i.e. sequence of bytes which follow the encoding rules of certificates (such certificates are often self-signed, because the format for a certificate has a non-optional slot for a "signature", so there must be something in that slot).

Since this is non-standard, interpretation of certificate extension in such a certificate-like structure is open to local variants. Some implementations interpret the `Key Usage` extension in a root certificate in the ways explained above. Some ignore that extension altogether.

In general, it is safe (for interoperability) to fill root CA certificates with contents which would be perfectly valid if that "certificate" was a real one, instead of a convenient encoding vessel for a trust anchor.

Comment: The signature field is not optional, but almost nobody actually verifies it, so any sequence of bytes will be "accepted" (when importing a certificate, Windows uses that signature to suggest, at the GUI level, to send the certificate to the "trusted root" or the "intermediate CA" store, depending on whether the certificate is self-signed or not; but that's only in the import interface; once the certificate has been stored in the "trusted root", its signature field, though present, is wholly ignored).

Comment: The self-signature on a root CA certificate has no meaning: if the attacker replaces the public key with a copy of his own, then he can _also_ replace the signature with a self-signature which matches the altered certificate contents. It would be a delusion to believe that the self-signature adds any security in that context.

Comment: `Therefore, nothing prevents the Key Usage extension from containing other flags. Alternatively, the Key Usage extension may be missing altogether; this is equivalent to "all usages allowed".` - 

Is there any RFC that describes your statement above? It seems odd that assigning no key usages would mean that all key usages are allowed.