# Why does curl/NSS encryption library not allow a CA with the extended key usage by SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, rfc

## Problem

curl rejects the CA certificate below with **60) Certificate type not approved for application** for SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE. I would like to understand the reason.

[SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Security/x509_Certificates)

> A certificate has an extended key usage extension that does not assert a required usage, or an end-entity certificate asserts the id-kp-OCSPSigning usage when it shouldn't

Because as far as I looked at the RFC 3218, it looks all the required extended key usage extensions are asserted.

#### The curl command and reply

```
$ sudo curl -ivL \
>     --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt \
>     --key  /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key \
>     --cacert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt \
> https://ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:10250/healthz
*   Trying 172.31.4.117...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal (172.31.4.117) port 10250 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
*   start date: Dec 23 05:13:30 2017 GMT
*   expire date: Dec 23 05:13:30 2018 GMT
*   common name: ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
*   issuer: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
* NSS error -8101 (SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE)
* Certificate type not approved for application.
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Certificate type not approved for application.
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

***curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server*** and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

### CA certificate rejected by curl

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 23 05:13:30 2017 GMT
            Not After : Dec 23 05:13:30 2018 GMT
        Subject: CN=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal@1514006010
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d5:48:65:86:4e:ec:08:a1:b1:26:4b:da:7c:e0:
                    d9:d0:16:96:93:9e:c0:f3:78:cb:27:a9:e1:99:d2:
                    10:73:70:e5:1e:ee:03:1a:55:51:29:c6:2e:62:71:
                    d9:c2:72:19:d3:36:41:9b:ef:74:ac:20:97:25:1b:
                    63:55:96:07:4d:02:01:c9:44:7d:f9:63:2b:50:98:
                    2a:fb:b7:03:0d:96:6d:6a:36:9d:93:ad:2c:6a:87:
                    7d:b8:aa:22:ca:f2:c4:a6:90:24:2b:4c:94:d1:4a:
                    3c:0d:c5:fa:48:fb:e5:82:30:17:f9:67:3a:1d:9b:
                    85:7a:bc:e9:e9:79:48:0e:53:41:fc:64:3a:c3:c1:
                    7e:ae:51:23:17:8e:db:1e:4c:99:56:a4:77:ad:74:
                    64:64:ab:a7:84:02:40:ec:c8:b1:51:2b:b3:80:7e:
                    b2:51:68:5c:d2:40:9d:f3:54:b9:76:2d:47:ea:f4:
                    51:c6:03:e9:c4:63:5c:5a:a7:7e:9a:97:89:45:99:
                    e8:a0:9b:5d:1d:15:94:f9:c9:2a:a4:19:a2:07:25:
                    2b:e6:0e:50:63:c0:6e:f9:a0:a7:ce:4a:ca:97:17:
                    64:2f:8a:e2:39:d5:e2:c9:c7:c4:53:f1:6e:14:22:
                    ca:02:cb:8a:0c:47:68:31:f2:0b:20:2c:a3:a5:5f:
                    cd:95
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         bc:84:b2:5c:c1:a5:52:b7:03:ae:9c:53:47:4b:ca:8b:4a:90:
         7f:41:0f:09:ff:77:5e:cc:7c:2c:0c:bc:37:71:c9:22:4e:7f:
         eb:9f:a9:f8:04:1d:8d:39:67:52:46:9c:3b:dc:d8:1f:b0:00:
         64:ed:2f:bf:8f:4c:8c:f2:6b:96:ec:99:66:19:39:1d:11:77:
         52:6b:a8:f4:88:e1:ad:6b:61:af:bd:c0:fc:f7:c2:37:a2:c2:
         7f:cc:de:98:a4:61:25:e2:78:b2:ab:94:31:0d:8f:2f:92:7b:
         4a:4f:5b:1c:c2:e8:bd:43:cb:78:0e:f2:4b:b9:a5:54:0c:46:
         0f:b0:92:f8:3c:57:08:6a:df:a4:cd:78:63:23:2f:13:12:7f:
         89:7f:3d:c0:dd:c7:33:8d:55:76:10:38:47:2b:16:ce:d0:93:
         c4:9e:28:42:1e:2b:f4:78:15:dd:89:1e:67:a5:a1:a1:13:30:
         9a:2f:60:82:71:db:29:47:af:e7:61:71:1c:d6:72:27:61:17:
         e1:31:aa:ee:84:0d:53:f8:66:18:49:34:5d:fb:50:fb:4f:c7:
         b5:a1:8e:34:86:81:25:ad:31:d4:5c:9e:da:8d:08:85:a9:91:
         c6:f8:83:c7:23:57:11:04:dc:90:5a:c9:5a:bf:dd:3c:9c:6a:
         17:d8:d0:1f
```

### Research

The kubernetes GitHub says:

- [Change self signed certificates to not include extended key usage #311](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/311)
- [Switch to wget for integration apiserver checks](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/commit/11f18f3d17a4ab5d4789ff38ce3f320edf5d77d2)

> The NSS encryption library does not allow a CA to be used with the extended key usage present, at least in the way we are currently doing so. The generated self signed certificates extension section looks like:

```
...
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:localhost, IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:127.0.0.1
```

### [RFC 3218](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280.txt)

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
```

and

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE
```

should be satisfying RFC 3218 **4.2.1.3  Key Usage**.

> The key usage extension defines the purpose (e.g., encipherment,
>      signature, certificate signing) of the key contained in the
>      certificate.  The usage restriction might be employed when a key that
>      could be used for more than one operation is to be restricted.
>      ...
>   
>   The **keyCertSign** bit is asserted when the subject public key is
>         used for **verifying a signature on public key certificates**.  If the
>         keyCertSign bit is asserted, then t**he cA bit in the basic
>         constraints extension (section 4.2.1.10) MUST also be asserted**.

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication
```

should be satisfying RFC 3218 **4.2.1.13  Extended Key Usage**

> If the extension is present, then the certificate MUST only be used
>      for one of the purposes indicated.  If multiple purposes are
>      indicated the application need not recognize all purposes indicated,
>      as long as the intended purpose is present.  Certificate using
>      applications MAY require that a particular purpose be indicated in
>      order for the certificate to be acceptable to that application.
>   
>      If a CA includes extended key usages to satisfy such applications,
>      but does not wish to restrict usages of the key, the CA can include
>      the special keyPurposeID anyExtendedKeyUsage.  If the
>      anyExtendedKeyUsage keyPurposeID is present, the extension SHOULD NOT
>      be critical.
>   
>      If a certificate contains both a key usage extension and an extended
>      key usage extension, then both extensions MUST be processed
>      independently and the certificate MUST only be used for a purpose
>      consistent with both extensions.  If there is no purpose consistent
>      with both extensions, then the certificate MUST NOT be used for any
>      purpose.
>   
>      ...
>   
>       id-kp-serverAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 1 }
>       -- TLS WWW server authentication
>       -- Key usage bits that may be consistent: digitalSignature,
>       -- keyEncipherment or keyAgreement

[Root certificate key usage (non-self-signed end entity)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/root-certificate-key-usage-non-self-signed-end-entity) suggests it would be OK not to have cRLSign/CRL signing flag.

> Since a CA is supposed to issue certificate and CRL, it should have, on a general basis, the keyCertSign and cRLSign flags. These two flags are sufficient. If the CA does not intend to sign its own CRL, then it may omit the cRLSign flag;

### Question

So why curl thinks the CA certificate does not assert a required usage?

### Related

- [Key usage extensions and extended key usage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_keyusageextensionsandextendedkeyusage_r.html)
- [Missing 'Key Usage' on a CA certificate: can sign certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169765/missing-key-usage-on-a-ca-certificate-can-sign-certificates)
- [SSL Certs issued with PKI backend don't work with firefox: sec_error_inadequate_cert_type #987](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/987)
- [curl: (60) Certificate type not approved for application where wget works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965359)
- [GitHub - Network Security Services](https://github.com/nss-dev/nss)
- [curl source code control](https://curl.haxx.se/dev/source.html)

Comment: The output of curl shows that it is using the NSS library. Your question includes a description that NSS will not allow extended key usage within a CA certificate. But your certificate is a CA certificate and has extended key usage. Take all these three things together and your question is answered.

Comment: Hello @SteffenUllrich. I am not clear why curl rejects the CA certificate which (to me) is valid RFC 3218 compliant. Would like to know why it rejects. Is it the expected behaviour and I miss something, or wget behaviour accepting it is the correct behaviour then is it curl issue?

Comment: Thus, you are essentially asking if the behavior of NSS which is described in your question is a feature or a bug? I.e. this statement: *"The NSS encryption library does not allow a CA to be used with the extended key usage present, at least in the way we are currently doing so."*. If this is the case, then you might just remove everything from your question which is not necessary to understand this statement (in other words: most of the question) and focus on this statement instead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich not clear with your intention. If the curl/nss behaviour is aligned with RFC 3218 is relevant to me. If the CA cert does satisfy what RFC 3218 says (I am not 100% sure hence looking for input too), then it comes to the question if it is curl bug/nss or not. If it does not satisfy, then it comes to the question what is wrong with the cert. Either way, "Why does curl/NSS encryption library not allow a CA with the extended key usage by SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE?" is still the question to me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, if you have insights, please share to help me understand. I appreciate your help to better ask the question or how to ask the question but that is another thing. Do you know/think if this is a NSS bug? If so why? Do you have the answer why "NSS error -8101 (SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE)" is caused and which part of the cert is the cause? If so please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compress your long and extensive question to the core: You are are essentially asking if the behavior of the NSS library to fail with SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_CERT_TYPE for your specific certificate and usage is correct.

The certificate you are trying to use as CA (using `--cacert` argument in curl)  contains both Basic Constraints CA:true and also various Extended Key Usage attributes. You correctly [cite an issue from kubernetes/go-client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/311) which describes that combining (certain) Extended Key Usage and CA:true causes the problem you see. If you follow the second link on this issue it will lead you to [this issue for mozilla:pkix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1049176) where the problem is discussed in detail and the behavior explained. To cite from the first comment:

> From rfc 5280, section 4.2.1.12: (Extended Key Usage)
>      If the extension is present, then the certificate MUST only be used
>      for one of the purposes indicated.

Given that the Extended Key Usage in your certificate only allow certain key usages and don't allow `anyExtendedKeyUsage` the basic constraint CA:true will be ignored, which means that this certificate cannot be used as CA certificate as you attempt to do. For a deeper discussions on how to interpret RFC 5280 in this case please see [the issue at Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1049176).

Comment: Thanks. Understood the curl behaviour is correct. The certificate can only be used as a server certificate and cannot be a CA certificate.

Comment: With NSS, it's seems that if `CA:TRUE` is a critical or non-critical basic constraint, then even if the `anyExtendedKeyUsage` OID is set, it still won't accept a self-signed certificate for TLS server authentication. With `certutil -V` and `-u L` ("SSL CA"), it's accepted as a CA, but, as per `-u V` ("SSL server") it reports "Certificate type not approved for application". [Comment #8 in the Mozilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1049176#c8) suggests NSS has an overly strict interpretation of the RFC, but there're appear to be no further developments to address it.